# How do I make old-school pixel perfect bevels like this with CSS?

Tags: css, pixel

I have been trying hard to replicate pixel perfect borders/bevels in CSS for something that seems to be very simple. I want the code to be minimal and as straight forward as possible, but it becomes overly complicated, while still not doing exactly what I aim for.

The original is from the early 2000's and it's made with tables and image backgrounds. I thought this would be an easy task with CSS, but the more I get into it, the more complicated it gets.

Can someone help with this challenge?

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #6487db;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.box-content {
  background-color: #E1E7F6;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.box h2 {
  padding-left: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: #90abeb;
  border-bottom-color: #486cc2;
  border-left-color: #90abeb;
  border-right-color: #486cc2;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #6487db;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e5ebf9;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  letter-spacing: 0.02rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #3c57b0;
}

.box h3 {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: #162770;
  font-family: trebuchet ms;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.box .text {
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 8px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="box-content">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <div class="text">This is some text.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

Comment: If you have an attempt, it would help to include it in the question.

Comment: _I have been trying hard to replicate pixel perfect borders/bevels_ well, what have you tried? Post your code here. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).